# Cannot get AdMob ads to show up in libgdx game

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, admob

I am trying to create an admob banner in my ad, but it doesnt show up, this is what I get in logcat:

```
02-23 14:52:11.943: I/Ads(13358): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
02-23 14:52:11.943: I/Ads(13358): Ad finished loading.
02-23 14:53:11.992: I/Ads(13358): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
```

In my code, i am using 2 screens, one called TitleScreen and one called GameScreen, and my game class is called SimonSays.

Here is my android code in MainActivity.java:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    View gameView = initializeForView(new SimonSays(), true);

    AdView AdView = new AdView(this);
    AdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    AdView.setAdUnitId("***"); //Secret
    AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adRequest.addTestDevice("7C4216C9F2879CE166853D136DCC4F32"); //My Galaxy S4
    AdView.loadAd(adRequest.build());

    layout.addView(gameView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    layout.addView(AdView, adParams);

    setContentView(layout);


    initialize(new SimonSays(), cfg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing your game twice. One here:

```
View gameView = initializeForView(new SimonSays(), true);
```

And the other one here:

```
initialize(new SimonSays(), cfg);
```

Delete the second one, and use the **cfg** configuration in the first one. Like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
View gameView = initializeForView(new SimonSays(), cfg); //<-- notice the change

AdView AdView = new AdView(this);
AdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
AdView.setAdUnitId("***"); //Secret
AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
adRequest.addTestDevice("7C4216C9F2879CE166853D136DCC4F32"); //My Galaxy S4
AdView.loadAd(adRequest.build());

layout.addView(gameView);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

layout.addView(AdView, adParams);

setContentView(layout);
```